# Editing json text http3

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a post function with a json in it. I wanted to know if you could use an "edit text"  to change values in the json.

There is a section in the json with a total, I want to change that total with edit text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. You'd basically need to get the value in the `EditText`, and then you can assign the value to the json using the [put](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#put(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)) method of `JSONObject`. (If your json is a string, you'll need to create a [JSONObject from the json string](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject(java.lang.String)) before you can put the new value in it)

You'll basically need to do something along the following lines,

```
val mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/json")

//Create JSONObject from json string
val jsonObject = JSONObject("{\r\n  \"dateTime\": \"2019-07-01T00:00:00-07:00\",\r\n  \"apiOptions\": [\r\n    \"ALLOWPARTIALAUTH\"\r\n  ],\r\n  \"amount\": {\r\n    \"cashback\": 20,\r\n    \"surcharge\": 5,\r\n    \"tax\": 15,\r\n    \"tip\": 20,\r\n    \"total\": 160\r\n  },\r\n  \"card\": {\r\n    \"entryMode\": \"M\",\r\n    \"expirationDate\": 1230,\r\n    \"number\": \"4321000000001119\",\r\n    \"present\": \"N\",\r\n    \"securityCode\": {\r\n      \"indicator\": \"1\",\r\n      \"value\": \"333\"\r\n    }\r\n  },\r\n  \"clerk\": {\r\n    \"numericId\": 1576\r\n  },\r\n  \"customer\": {\r\n    \"addressLine1\": \"65 Easy St\",\r\n    \"firstName\": \"John\",\r\n    \"lastName\": \"Smith\",\r\n    \"postalCode\": \"65144\"\r\n  },\r\n  \"transaction\": {\r\n    \"invoice\": \"192029\",\r\n    \"notes\": \"Transaction notes are added here\",\r\n    \"hotel\": {\r\n      \"arrivalDateTime\": \"2018-06-18T15:39:01.594-07:00\",\r\n      \"departureDateTime\": \"2018-06-21T09:18:23.283-07:00\",\r\n      \"primaryChargeType\": 1,\r\n      \"specialCode\": 1,\r\n      \"additionalCharges\": {\r\n        \"giftShop\": \"Y\",\r\n        \"laundry\": \"Y\",\r\n        \"miniBar\": \"Y\",\r\n        \"other\": \"Y\",\r\n        \"restaurant\": \"Y\",\r\n        \"telephone\": \"Y\"\r\n      },\r\n      \"roomRates\": [\r\n        {\r\n          \"nights\": 2,\r\n          \"rate\": 159.95\r\n        },\r\n        {\r\n          \"nights\": 3,\r\n          \"rate\": 125.38\r\n        }\r\n      ]\r\n    },\r\n    \"purchaseCard\": {\r\n      \"customerReference\": \"D019D09309F2\",\r\n      \"destinationPostalCode\": \"94719\",\r\n      \"productDescriptors\": [\r\n        \"Hamburger\",\r\n        \"Fries\",\r\n        \"Soda\",\r\n        \"Cookie\"\r\n      ]\r\n    }\r\n  },\r\n  \"lighthouse\": {\r\n    \"data\": \"eyJsaWdodGhvdXNlIjp7ImVtcGxveWVlaWQiOjEyMzQsImRldmljZWlkIjoiMTIzU0FCViJ9fQ==\"\r\n  }\r\n}")

//Get numerical value from EditText
val newTotal:Int? = editText.text.toString().toIntOrNull()
if (newTotal != null) {
    //If it's a valid Int value, then put it in the JSONObject
    //Note - 'total' is inside another json given by the value 'amount'
    jsonObject.getJSONObject("amount").put("total", newTotal)
}

val body = RequestBody.create(
            mediaType,
            jsonObject.toString()
        )
```

Comment: would you like me to show the code, i am not sure how to do it.

Comment: Sure, add the xml with the `EditText` and the json function.

Comment: ill send it as a Answer Your Question

Comment: I've updated my answer. If it works then upvote and mark the answer as correct (or feel free to add a comment if you face any more issues). Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code.

```
        //this tells the program that it is going to be using http3 to post the api
        val client = OkHttpClient()
//This chooses what is going to be sent to the api. The media type is basically if it is going to be text javascript kotlin json ect.

        val mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/json")
        //This is where the body is created or at least ready to form. What is does is set up a value for where you input the json you want to send to the api.

        val body = RequestBody.create(
            mediaType,
            "{\r\n  \"dateTime\": \"2019-07-01T00:00:00-07:00\",\r\n  \"apiOptions\": [\r\n    \"ALLOWPARTIALAUTH\"\r\n  ],\r\n  \"amount\": {\r\n    \"cashback\": 20,\r\n    \"surcharge\": 5,\r\n    \"tax\": 15,\r\n    \"tip\": 20,\r\n    \"total\": 160\r\n  },\r\n  \"card\": {\r\n    \"entryMode\": \"M\",\r\n    \"expirationDate\": 1230,\r\n    \"number\": \"4321000000001119\",\r\n    \"present\": \"N\",\r\n    \"securityCode\": {\r\n      \"indicator\": \"1\",\r\n      \"value\": \"333\"\r\n    }\r\n  },\r\n  \"clerk\": {\r\n    \"numericId\": 1576\r\n  },\r\n  \"customer\": {\r\n    \"addressLine1\": \"65 Easy St\",\r\n    \"firstName\": \"John\",\r\n    \"lastName\": \"Smith\",\r\n    \"postalCode\": \"65144\"\r\n  },\r\n  \"transaction\": {\r\n    \"invoice\": \"192029\",\r\n    \"notes\": \"Transaction notes are added here\",\r\n    \"hotel\": {\r\n      \"arrivalDateTime\": \"2018-06-18T15:39:01.594-07:00\",\r\n      \"departureDateTime\": \"2018-06-21T09:18:23.283-07:00\",\r\n      \"primaryChargeType\": 1,\r\n      \"specialCode\": 1,\r\n      \"additionalCharges\": {\r\n        \"giftShop\": \"Y\",\r\n        \"laundry\": \"Y\",\r\n        \"miniBar\": \"Y\",\r\n        \"other\": \"Y\",\r\n        \"restaurant\": \"Y\",\r\n        \"telephone\": \"Y\"\r\n      },\r\n      \"roomRates\": [\r\n        {\r\n          \"nights\": 2,\r\n          \"rate\": 159.95\r\n        },\r\n        {\r\n          \"nights\": 3,\r\n          \"rate\": 125.38\r\n        }\r\n      ]\r\n    },\r\n    \"purchaseCard\": {\r\n      \"customerReference\": \"D019D09309F2\",\r\n      \"destinationPostalCode\": \"94719\",\r\n      \"productDescriptors\": [\r\n        \"Hamburger\",\r\n        \"Fries\",\r\n        \"Soda\",\r\n        \"Cookie\"\r\n      ]\r\n    }\r\n  },\r\n  \"lighthouse\": {\r\n    \"data\": \"eyJsaWdodGhvdXNlIjp7ImVtcGxveWVlaWQiOjEyMzQsImRldmljZWlkIjoiMTIzU0FCViJ9fQ==\"\r\n  }\r\n}"
        )
```